# sudo -u username -s "cmd arg" returns command not found

Tags: sudo, quoting

I used to execute the command:

```
sudo -u elasticsearch -s "ulimit -Hn"
```

and it was returning the value of ulimit -Hn as seen by user elasticsearch until I tried it on Ubuntu 11.10.  There it returns:

```
/bin/bash: ulimit -Hn: command not found
```

I tried a few different commands, and when I use an argument I always get "command not found":

```
$ sudo -u elasticsearch -s "ls all.sh"
/bin/bash: ls all.sh: command not found
```

Any ideas on how can I execute a command that requires arguments through `sudo`?

Comment: why the `-s`? Just keep the normal shell and use it to execute commands. Such as `sudo -u elasticsearch ls all.sh`. If `elasticsearch` has an unusable default shell, use `-s bash` **before** the actual command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to remove the double-quotes. It is trying to run a command called "ulimit -Hn" as a single command, spaces and all. `-s` needs to be the last `sudo` option on the `sudo` command line, and all following arguments are passed to `$SHELL -c` to execute.

```
sudo -u elasticsearch -s ulimit -Hn
```

I guess the way `-s` is processed has changed, as the current way allows you to pass arguments with spaces to `$SHELL` by escaping them on the command line:

```
$ touch '/tmp/foo bar'
$ sudo -s rm '/tmp/foo bar'
```

The old method of argument handling would split that `'/tmp/foo bar'` argument into two, breaking the command.

Comment: where did you test that it would *not* split the command?

Comment: @Zarathustra That was five years ago - I can't remember back that far. I'd suggest digging through the sudo source code history - you should be able to find when the behaviour changed.